Python: efficient unpacking large dictionary with list of strings as values to list of lists of keys
I have a large dictionary with lists of strings as values. These strings can be duplicated. I would like to convert this dictionary to a list of lists of keys. The goal is to correlate the keys of original dictionary to unique strings so that later I can easily pick up all the keys for any unique string in subsequent analysis.
A simulation function is as follows:
import cProfile
import time
import string
import random
import collections
import numpy as np
from typing import Dict, List, Set


def test_large_dict():
    char_pool: str = string.ascii_uppercase
    # simulate a large dictionary with 300,001 keys, 10,000 unique strings.
    test_dict: Dict[int, List[str]] = collections.defaultdict(list)
    num_keys: int = 300001
    str_nums: np.ndarray = np.random.randint(10, 300, size=num_keys)
    str_len: List[int] = np.random.randint(7, 30, size=10000).tolist()
    rand_strs: List[str] = [
        ''.join(random.choice(char_pool) for _ in range(str_len[i]))
        for i in range(10000)
    ]
    for i in range(1, num_keys):
        # no. of strings in current value: str_nums[i])
        test_dict[i] = [random.choice(rand_strs) for _ in range(str_nums[i])]

    # In original dictionary
    print(f"1: {test_dict[1]}")
    print(f"2: {test_dict[2]}")

    # ===========================================
    # The block I want to optimise.
    t = time.time()
    str_index: Dict[str, int] = {}
    key_lists: List[Set[int]] = []
    k: int = 0
    for ix, str_list in test_dict.items():
        for s in str_list:
            if s in str_index:
                g = str_index[s]
                key_lists[g].add(ix)
            else:
                str_index[s] = k
                key_lists.append({ix})
                k += 1
    print(f"Elapsed time for the conversion: {time.time() - t:.2f} seconds.")
    # ===========================================


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cProfile.run("test_large_dict()", sort="tottime")

The test time:
Elapsed time for the conversion: 24.77 seconds.

Profiling results are:
355043899 function calls in 148.398 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 46487731   37.495    0.000  109.065    0.000 random.py:341(choice)
 46487731   35.055    0.000   56.797    0.000 random.py:242(_randbelow_with_getrandbits)
        1   27.915   27.915  147.832  147.832 test_proteolysis.py:104(test_large_dict)
 92975462   14.773    0.000   14.773    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
 76097488   13.163    0.000   13.163    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.Random' objects}
 46297043   10.721    0.000   10.721    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
 46487731    8.579    0.000    8.579    0.000 {method 'bit_length' of 'int' objects}
        1    0.566    0.566  148.398  148.398 <string>:1(<module>)
   190688    0.076    0.000    0.476    0.000 test_proteolysis.py:112(<genexpr>)
    10000    0.040    0.000    0.517    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.005    0.003    0.005    0.003 {method 'randint' of 'numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState' objects}
    10000    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        3    0.005    0.002    0.005    0.002 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'tolist' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000  148.398  148.398 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:71(_wrapreduction)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2979(prod)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2974(_prod_dispatcher)

Lots of time were spent to unpack this large dictionary into lists. Any more efficient way to unpack the large dictionary? I'm also free to any data structure to achieve the goal. In the provided example, I generated a dict str_index and list key_lists. The keys of str_index are unique strings, and values are the indexes of lists in the key_lists, so that all keys in original large dictionary for ith unique string are put in ith list in key_lists, e.g., all keys for ith unique string sj are key_lists[str_index[sj]].

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve. Having said that, your code emits "Elapsed time for the conversion: 8.83 seconds." on Apple M2 with Python 3.13.1.

your generation code uses random.choice in loops instead of random.choices. that's über slow. random.choice(char_pool) for _ in range(str_len[i]) should be random.choices(char_pool, k=str_len[i])

@SIGHUP I added lines #====... to indicate the block I would like to optimise. It's good to have a better computer to run. I want to know any better way to reduce the running time for the codes in the block.

it's obvious what block you want to optimise, but if you want us to run it you better have a fast generation

i've refactored things a bit to gain modularity
def algo1(test_dict):
    str_index: Dict[str, int] = {}
    key_lists: List[Set[int]] = []
    k: int = 0
    for ix, str_list in test_dict.items():
        for s in str_list:
            if s in str_index:
                g = str_index[s]
                key_lists[g].add(ix)
            else:
                str_index[s] = k
                key_lists.append({ix})
                k += 1
    return str_index, key_lists

def algo2(test_dict):
    counters = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for ix, str_list in test_dict.items():
        for s in set(str_list):
            counters[s].add(ix)

    str_index = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(counters.keys())}
    key_lists = list(counters.values())
    return str_index, key_lists

def algo3(test_dict):
    counters = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for ix, str_list in test_dict.items():
        for s in set(str_list):
            counters[s].append(ix)

    str_index = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(counters.keys())}
    key_lists = list(counters.values())
    return str_index, key_lists

and as expected the defaultdict(list) solution fares better then the defaultdict(set) one
Elapsed time for the algo1: 2.82 seconds.
Elapsed time for the algo2: 2.21 seconds.
Elapsed time for the algo3: 1.45 seconds.


Don't understand the mean of for k, v in Counter(str_list).items(). This only generates k the unique string and v the number of k in str_list. v > 1 will exclude the single k in the list in the dictionary. Seems better to use for s set(str_list).

haha i failed hard. the gain is small in the end but it's still ~25%
